# Is $S = \{ (x,y): x^2+y^2=\frac {1}{n^2}, n \in \mathbb N \wedge (x \in \mathbb Q \vee y \in \mathbb Q) \}$ countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am working on the following problem:

> Is the set $S = \left\{ (x,y): x^2+y^2=\frac {1}{n^2}, n \in \mathbb N \wedge (x \in \mathbb Q \vee y \in \mathbb Q) \right\}$ countable?

My answer is *yes*.

**Reason:**

For a fixed $n$, let $S_n = \left\{ (x,y): x^2+y^2=\frac {1}{n^2}, n \in \mathbb N \wedge (x \in \mathbb Q \vee y \in \mathbb Q) \right\}$.

Then $S_n = (\mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q) \cup \bigcup\limits_{r\in \mathbb Q}\left(\pm r, \pm\sqrt {\frac {1}{n^2}-r^2}\right)$ where $r <\frac {1}{n^2} $.

Clearly each set forming $S_n$ is countable, its union ($S_n$) is also countable.
As $S=\bigcup\limits_{n\in \mathbb N} S_n$, $S$ is also countable.

Am I correct? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$? Or just $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: There should be a $\pm$ for $y$.

Comment: @user477343 post edited.....

Comment: @Mikhail Katz post edited accordingly....

Comment: Is my answer correct?

Comment: The set of all pairs of rational numbers is countable and this set is a subset so, yes, of course, it is countable!

Comment: @user247327 It's not a subset of the set of pairs of rational numbers, but a subset of pairs in which one of them is rational. So the universe is $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{R}\cup\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{Q}$ which is uncountable.

Comment: @freakish yes because $a\lor b$ means $a$ **or** $b$. It's just that when we have an ordered group $(a_1, a_2,\ldots a_n)$, then if this group belongs to a set $X$, we write it as $X^n$, from what I'm taught. Unless it is not an ordered group and it is just individual members of the set $X$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually you have

$$S_n=L_n\cup R_n$$

where

$$L_n=\bigg\{\bigg(r,\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2}-r^2}\bigg)\ \bigg|\ r\in \mathbb{Q}\text{ and }r^2\leq\frac{1}{n^2}\bigg\}$$
$$R_n=\bigg\{\bigg(\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2}-r^2},r\bigg)\ \bigg|\ r\in \mathbb{Q}\text{ and }r^2\leq\frac{1}{n^2}\bigg\}$$

Note the different order in $L_n$ and $R_n$ (that's the only difference between them). Those sets correspond to $x\in\mathbb{Q}\vee y\in\mathbb{Q}$ condition which is **or**, not **and**. And with this simple modification your reasoning is correct.

Comment: Should it not be  $S_n = L_n \bigcup R_n \bigcup Q_n $?

Comment: @shwetha No, $Q_n$ is the indexing set (see: $r\in Q_n$) used in the definition of $L_n$ and $R_n$. I could just remove $Q_n$ completely and say $r\in\mathbb{Q}$ whenever $\sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2}-r^2}$ is real.

Comment: Thank you! Got it!

Comment: @shwetha If you agreed to solution , accept one of solution that you find useful.

Comment: Sir, how does it follows that, $L_n$ and $R_n$ are countable? Please elaborate

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi both are index (there's a surjection from) by $\{\pm 1\}\times \mathbb{Q}$ which is countable.

Answer (score 3):

You made a minor formal mistake: when you say *'For a fixed $n$...'* you should not insert the $(n\in\mathbb N)$ clause in the set definition as it means 'for any natural value of $n$'. Instead you might add it as a requirement to $n$ itself:

> For a fixed $n\color{red}{\in \mathbb N}$, let $S_n = \left\{ (x,y): x^2+y^2=\frac {1}{n^2}, x \in \mathbb Q \vee y \in \mathbb Q \right\}$.

Apart from that your solution seems correct to me: there are countably many $n$ values (hence $x,y$ equations of circles), and each circle has countably many points with $x\in\mathbb Q$ and countably many points with $y\in\mathbb Q$ (these two sets not disjoint), hence $S$ is a union of countably infinite family of countably infinite sets. This implies it is equipollent with $\mathbb N^3$ and so it is countably infinite.

Answer (score 0):

Given that $~S = \{ (x,y): x^2+y^2=\frac {1}{n^2}, n \in \mathbb N \wedge (x \in \mathbb Q \vee y \in \mathbb Q) \}~.$
So there doesn't exist any pair of $(x,y)$ other than $(1/n,0)$ and $(0,1/n)$, for all $n \in \mathbb N$, that satisfies the given condition.
Now we know that $~n \in \mathbb N ~$  is countable and countable union of countable sets is countable. Hence $~S=(1/n,0)\cup(0,1/n)~$ is countable.